# react-native-builder-bob package build fails using npm

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm

I have created a custom helper package for my `react-native` projects. Even-though everything works when it build through `yarn`, when I use `npm` all the `react-native` references gives out errors.

ex -

```
npm ERR! prepareGitDep src/Components/CloseButton/index.tsx:19:6 - error TS2786: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep   Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 19     <View style={[styles.main, {  left: position, bottom: position } ]}>
```

I am using `react-native-builder-bob` create the package.

**Environment**

- MacOS
- npm: 9.6.7
- node: v14.21.2
- react: 17.0.2
- react-native: 0.68.2

And here is the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test-pkg",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "lib/commonjs/index",
  "module": "lib/module/index",
  "types": "lib/typescript/index.d.ts",
  "react-native": "src/index",
  "source": "src/index",
  "files": [
    "src",
    "lib",
    "android",
    "ios",
    "cpp",
    "test-pkg.podspec",
    "!lib/typescript/example",
    "!android/build",
    "!ios/build",
    "!**/__tests__",
    "!**/__fixtures__",
    "!**/__mocks__"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "typescript": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\"",
    "prepare": "bob build",
    "build": "bob build",
    "release": "release-it",
    "example": "yarn --cwd example",
    "bootstrap": "yarn example && yarn && yarn example pods"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "repository": "https://github.com/......",
  "license": "MIT",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arkweid/lefthook": "^0.7.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.2",
    "@release-it/conventional-changelog": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "@types/lodash.clamp": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "0.68.0",
    "commitlint": "^17.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-builder-bob": "^0.18.3",
    "release-it": "^15.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.21"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-svg": "*"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/example/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/lib/"
    ]
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ]
  },
  "release-it": {
    "git": {
      "commitMessage": "chore: release ${version}",
      "tagName": "v${version}"
    },
    "npm": {
      "publish": true
    },
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },
    "plugins": {
      "@release-it/conventional-changelog": {
        "preset": "angular"
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "extends": [
      "@react-native-community",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": [
        "error",
        {
          "quoteProps": "consistent",
          "singleQuote": true,
          "tabWidth": 2,
          "trailingComma": "es5",
          "useTabs": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "node_modules/",
    "lib/"
  ],
  "prettier": {
    "quoteProps": "consistent",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": false
  },
  "react-native-builder-bob": {
    "source": "src",
    "output": "lib",
    "targets": [
      "commonjs",
      "module",
      [
        "typescript",
        {
          "project": "tsconfig.build.json"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-spring/native": "^9.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "lodash-move": "^1.1.1",
    "lodash.clamp": "^4.0.3",
    "lodash.samplesize": "^4.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.4.1"
  }
}
```

When the package is linked locally its working without any issues, but the biggest problem is when you use install the package trough `gitHub` due to it only use `npm` for the installation.